# Having issues removing a specific Registry key using GPO Preferences

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry

Hello I attempting to remove the following registry key using GPO Preferences:

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}
```

The key just wont delete.
I have the following Registry preferences:

```
Action: Delete

Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE Key Path:
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}
```

Value name is blank
Default is unchecked.

Is there something simple that I'm forgetting?

Comment: Can you show us the screenshot and paste the XML from the GPP? To do this copy the item and paste into notepad.

Comment: And have confirmed that the GPP is applying by using RSOP?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing as well and initial research suggests it's not possible using the registry item with a delete option in GPO. That appears to only be used for deleting values. The XML for such an entry looks like this:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Registry clsid="{9CD4B2F4-923D-47f5-A062-E897DD1DAD50}" name="{CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000}" status="{CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000}" image="3" changed="2013-12-19 18:43:59" uid="{7EE3632D-A3C9-484A-ABE9-556DF074718C}" bypassErrors="1"><Properties action="D" displayDecimal="0" default="0" hive="HKEY_CURRENT_USER" key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings\{CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000}" name="" type="REG_SZ" value=""/></Registry>

Comment: That suggests to me that it's trying to delete a value where the name = "". Unless of course the GPO code says "If name is blank, then remove the entire key". The other option (not as neat) is to import a .REG file - that can delete entire keys AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

Finish your Key Path value with a '`\`'  :

**Hive:** `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

**Key Path:** `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\`

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the Policy is applied using the RSOP.msc
2. Check the permissions on the current regkey "{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}" I think this is the issue, probably have applied wrong permissions.
3. Make sure to Apply the GPO to All Authenticated Users and Domain Computers in the Security Filtering.